# Get temperature via ADC of microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, adc

I want to manipulate the physical value of temperature. Here is the characteristic of this µC:

Resolution: 12 bits
Supply: 5 V
Min Mesure: -45
Max Mesure: 75
Min ADC IN: 0.4
Max ADC IN: 4.8

Here is the formula which i used:

```
 Value = (Digital value * Max ADC IN) / 4095.0;
```

I used the rule of three.

```
Max ADC IN (4.8) ===> 4095 (depends on the resolution (12 bits)) 
Value            ===> Digital value from ADC
```

If I use this formula, it is sufficient to read the physical value?

I don't have the datasheet of the sensor, the microcontroller is 68HCs12.

Comment: How did you get to this formula?

Comment: What is your accuracy of measurement? Since the controller is of 12 bit so it can sense a variation of approx 1 mV or total number of measurement steps are 4096 which can be sets in between -45 to 75

Comment: @SanjeevKumar:  I mean the total number of measurement steps are 4096 which can be sets in between -45 to 75. And ADC IN is the ADC input voltage.

Comment: What kind of sensor? For example, for a thermistor, the characteristics are not linear (the way you have assumed). You'll need to measure the voltage of the circuit (after filtering perhaps) at a number of points and then perhaps fit a curve and then use that to calculate the temperature.

Comment: @physics yes and Since the controller minimum ADC Voltage is 0.4 and approximately one step is of 1mV so the next minimum ADC voltage that can be sense is 0.401V if there is a need of all 4096 Steps. That is the reason why i asked the accuracy of your measurement. suppose your accuracy is 1 Deg C then total number of steps will be used is 121 (-45 to 75). But if your accuracy is 0.5 Deg C then total number of steps need to use will be around 121*2=242.

Comment: @captainsomewhere: I want to measure the instantaneous value of the temperature. There is another smart linearized circuit, it used to linearise the Temp sensor.The output voltage's sensor is between 0.4 and 4.8 (i.e -45 and 75 when it passed via ADC). Finally the value physic which i want to get it is between -46°C and 140°C. The resolution is 0.125°C and the accuracy is 1°C.

Comment: @SanjeevKumar: The accuracy is 1°C. My formula is right? i can use it ?

Comment: @physics: As per me it is sufficient to read the physical value of accuracy 1 Deg C.

Comment: It is not clear to me how you expect to measure a temperature greater than 75 degrees when you state that is the upper limit of your ADC. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I think your formula is ok. As mentioned by Sanjeev, do not forget to get the approximate number of samples you need to get the accuracy you need.

Here is an example of an ADC_get_value routine that I used time ago. It uses a similar formula:

```
/* Function name    :   unsigned char ConvertAdcvalueToFuelLevel( unsigned int x )
* Crated by     :   
* Description   :   This function converts from ADC values to its equivalent voltage and then returns a number
*                   between 0 - 255 representing voltages between 0 - 5000mV.
*                   The receiver must multiply the returned value by 19.6078 in order to get the equivalent
*                   voltage.
*                   The transfer function for the hardware used on the ADC input is:
*                   f(x)= 0.999*x       x:volts
******************************************************************************************************************/
unsigned char ConvertAdcvalueToFuelLevel( unsigned int x )
{
    unsigned int Voltage;
    unsigned int Offset = 5;        //15mV

    //Converts from ADC bits to voltage
    Voltage = ((unsigned long int)((unsigned long int)x * 4990))/4095;  //(x*Vref)/4095 (Millivolts)

    //The hardware used on the analog input is almost lineal between 0V and 4.2V.
    Voltage = (unsigned int)(0.999*Voltage) + Offset;
    return (unsigned char)(Voltage / 19.6078);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, 
I did not understand what do you mean by Offset?

Comment: I found that in my hardware the voltage value read by the ADC was slightly less than the voltage on the pin, so that, I decided to add an offset (of approx 5mV) in order to return the exact value that I was looking for.